# CakePHP does not send POST

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

After a lot of searches i found the trouble but i have no idea how to fix it.

When i set the form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` the CakePHP2 send an empty `$_POST`, the same case print `$this->request->data`. If i remove the add() method works as well.

It occurred after migrating from Windows to Debian, but i've checked permissions and edited php.ini (POST_MAX_SIZE and UPLOAD) and seems perfect.

`add()` code

```
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Request->create();

            if ($this->Request->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('A solicitação foi enviada com sucesso'));

                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The request could not be saved. Please, try again.'));  

                //print_r($this->Request->validationErrors);
```

Front-end

```
<div class="requests form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Request', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Enviar solicitação'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('hidden', 'label' => false, 'value' => AuthComponent::user('id')));
        echo $this->Form->input('hash', array('hidden', 'label' => false, 'value' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true))));
        echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'E-mail'));
        echo $this->Form->input('fullname', array('label' => 'Nome completo'));
        echo $this->Form->input('city_id', array('label' => 'Cidade'));
        //echo $this->Form->input('contract', array('label' => 'Contrato', 'type' => 'file', 'accept' => 'application/pdf'));
        echo $this->Form->file('contract');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Solicitar')); ?>
</div>
```

debug output

```
/app/Controller/RequestsController.php (line 77)
array()
```

note: i've removed the file upload block, i figured out is useless

Comment: First question Is your form POSTing or GETting?

Comment: I'm sending as POST.

Comment: debug($this->getRequest()->getData()); exit;  and post output in your question

Comment: @Salines I'm using CakePHP 2.x

Comment: ok, than debug($this->request->data); exit;

Comment: What is your front-end code?

Comment: Updated with code.

Answer (score 0):

After more time spent i found the trouble.

Someone has changed my internet security (by IE), after reseting the configuration everything works fine.

If someone knows why it affects when using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` i give you best answer.